# Problem with an Create Procedure or Insert Statment. Error Message: "error near @Parameter Name"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertInboxMessage
    @UserID uniqueIdentifier
    @Message nvarchar(Max)
AS 
   INSERT INTO Messages(UsersID, Messages)
   VALUES(@UserID, @Message)
```

It tells me that I have an error near @Message and that I must declare the scalar @UserID.

How do I correct those errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You are missing a Comma after the first parameter declaration**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertInboxMessage
    @UserID uniqueIdentifier,   -- Comma goes here!
    @Message nvarchar(Max)
AS
   INSERT INTO Messages(UsersID, Messages)
   VALUES(@UserID, @Message)
```

**References**

- [TSQL Create Procedure Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

Comment: Thanks ,, I am new to stored procedures ..I started making some today

Comment: No Problem. They are useful. You may also want to look into ScottGu's tutorial series on LINQ to SQL. http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/07/27/links-to-scott-guthrie-s-using-linq-to-sql-tutorials.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need a comma in between your variables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertInboxMessage

@UserID uniqueIdentifier,
@Message nvarchar(Max)
AS

INSERT INTO Messages(UsersID, Messages) VALUES(@UserID, @Message)
```